# How to bash cat or tee into a file, with sudo, with EOF, and with silent output

Tags: bash

I'm basically trying to write a script that sets up a virtual host, and I can't figure out the syntax needed to output a block of code to a root protected file, and then silence the output. I've been trying something like this:

```
sudo tee /etc/apache2/other/$NAME.conf <<EOF
NameVirtualHost *:80
<Virtualhost *:80>
        ServerName $NAME.dev
        ServerAlias www.$NAME.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/$NAME

        <Directory "/var/www/$NAME">
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
EOF &> /dev/null
```

But it doesn't suppress the output AND it includes the `&> /dev/null` in the file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Here document is different from a do-loop: the redirect should appear on the line with the command:

```
sudo tee /etc/apache2/other/$NAME.conf &>/dev/null <<EOF
NameVirtualHost *:80
<Virtualhost *:80>
        ServerName $NAME.dev
        ServerAlias www.$NAME.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/$NAME

        <Directory "/var/www/$NAME">
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
EOF
```

Comment: Just figured this out and came here to answer my own question, and this confirms it. Thanks!